# First boot VMware error, Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: vmware

When i first boot into VMware Player, I get this error: "Before you can run VMware, Several modules must be compiled and loaded:GCC."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Same for me.
Expensive licence, lack of service, lazy US corp, like cancer Microsoft with Teams for Linux. Though I experienced a worth usability with VirtualBox years before and shall compare again. There may follow-up fixes, VMware let the community do it.
Prosuments we are: work for your bought licence. Check here: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80807#
... and just wait. You may keep us updated.